# How to keep manifest file with d8 compile tool?

Tags: java, android, gradle, dx, android-d8

I build a jar for the Android platform with Gradle. When I use the `dx` command, it works well building a jar with manifest, but `dx` can't support Java 8 syntax. So I have to change compile tool to [`d8`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/d8), it supports Java 8 syntax but it removes the `MANIFEST.MF` file.
So how to keep manifest with the `d8` compile tool?

Build with `dx`:
[image]

Build with `d8`:
[image]

Gradle build script codes:

```
def jarPath = buildDir.absolutePath + "/libs"
def jarBaseName = "plugin"

task buildJar(dependsOn: build, type: Jar) {
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Jar-VersionCode': jarVersionCode
        }
    }
    from zipTree(file('build/intermediates/aar_main_jar/release/classes.jar'))
    // [archiveBaseName]-[archiveAppendix]-[archiveVersion]-[archiveClassifier].[archiveExtension]
    archiveBaseName = jarBaseName
    archiveAppendix = null
    archiveVersion = "$jarVersionName-$jarVersionCode"
    archiveClassifier = "release"
    archiveExtension = "jar"
    destinationDirectory = file(jarPath)
}

// dx --dex --output=output.jar input.jar
task buildDex1(dependsOn: buildJar, type: Exec) {
    workingDir jarPath
    executable "dx"
    args "--dex"
    args "--output=" + buildJar.archiveFileName.get()
    args buildJar.archiveFileName.get()
}

// d8 --release --output output.jar input.jar
task buildDex2(dependsOn: buildJar, type: Exec) {
    workingDir jarPath
    executable "d8"
    args "--release"
    args "--output"
    args buildJar.archiveFileName.get()
    args buildJar.archiveFileName.get()
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, why trying to build a `jar` with `.dex` files in it? `jar`files are as its name describes *Java Application Resources* files, should have a tree structures with packages and `.class` files(and other resources).  On the other hand `.aar`  (*Android Application Resources* ) are for storing `.dex` files.

Comment: @FacundoLarrosa The jar is built to hot update for Android App. The App will check to load a new version jar when opens.

Comment: Can't you achieve the same with an `.aar`?

Comment: @FacundoLarrosa I think `aar` is so fat to use, it has so many useless files. Hot update only needs bytecode and manifiest resource to tell the current version.

Comment: Why not building a good old `.jar` file with the bytecode in `.class` files as it is the `jar` lib standard?

Comment: @FacundoLarrosa dex jar is smaller than the standard jar in size

Comment: Is that much smaller to make it worthy? how much smaller are we talking about?